# Google Instant-style search in Rails3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, search

In my Rails app, I want to an **incremental search** (like autocomplete) through the `Customer` table in the DB, looking for names, and showing the results as you type, [Google Instant](http://www.google.com/instant/)-style.

My brief research for gems or examples that might help in this scenario didn't provide any useful results.
Is there **a Rails way** to implement this?

---

The only *issue* I can think of is that that having approx. 500k records in the DB (even if the name related columns are indexed) might slow down the responsiveness.
As a *solution* for that, the ajax request might be triggered only after typing in the first 4-5 characters.

Any other suggestions, leads, issues, ideas, comments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this: [Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

and here is Railscast for it: [TokenInput railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?autoplay=true)

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not at all familiar with ruby, I use [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) often. You can trigger it to run only after a certain number of characters are typed (See minLength in 'options').

Also you can pass additional parameters to your server side scripting. I pass one called Limit and set it to a sensible value (10 in most cases), I use this in the SQL query (where rownum <10), that way you don't hammer the database.